# Perl: What's the meaning of $hashName{"a","b","c"} = "d";?

Tags: perl, syntax

I'm trying to convert a large perl program to Java.  In an initialization function, it creates a hash using parentheses and then starts assigning values. But then the keys become pairs and triplets of comma-separated strings.  What does it mean?

````
 %par=( ...  )

 $par{"symbolChainAny"}=     "*";   # chain name if ...
 $par{"acc2Thresh"}=         16;    # threshold for...
 $par{"txt","copyright"}=       "elided";
 $par{"txt","contactEmail"}=    "elided";

 $par{"txt","modepred","sec"}=  "prediction of secondary structure";
 $par{"txt","modepred","cap"}=  "prediction of secondary structure caps";```
````

Answer (score 9):

```
$foo{$x, $y, $z}
```

is equivalent to

```
$foo{join($;, $x, $y, $z)}
```

where `$;` defaults to a control character (`"\x1C"`).

---

Not just similar...

```
$ diff \
   <( perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'$foo{$x,$y,$z}' 2>&1 ) \
   <( perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'$foo{join($;,$x,$y,$z)}' 2>&1 ) \
   && echo identical
identical
```

Comment: wow, this is a surprise (to me). I'd expect that it evaluates the comma, print warnings (twice), and use the last value.   And if I try to do this with a variable (`$v=$x,$y,$z`) it assigns `1` (success?) with warnings, and with parens around the list it does what I expected.  But if I add parens around the list in the hash key evaluation it still does what you say! I see this very example in perldoc -- but why? When is this `join` with `$;` triggered -- in what other contexts does that happen?

Comment: @zdim, The key expression is normally evaluated in scalar context. But when the it's the list/comma operator, a `join` is thrown in and it's evaluated in list context. The `l` after `entersub` means list context in `perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'$h{f(),g()}'`. Change it to `$h{f()}`, and it becomes `s` for scalar context. /// This is the only place `$;` is used.

Comment: @zdim https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Multi-dimensional-array-emulation - this is a perl4 feature that was retained in perl5

Comment: After many years or programming with Perl I never knew this peculiar feature. Is there a Perl::Critic::Policy that warns about using this syntax?

Comment: @BarneySchmale Not that I can find, but I added an [issue](https://github.com/Grinnz/Perl-Critic-Freenode/issues/35) to remind myself to add one to Perl::Critic::Freenode.